# Finding common elements from one file in a column of another file and output the entire row of the latter

Tags: unix, grep

I needed to extract all hits from one list (list.txt) which can be found in one of the columns of another (here in Data.txt) into a third (output.txt).

Data.txt (tab delimited)

```
some_data more_data other_data here yet_more_data etc
A B 2 Gee;Whiz;Hello 13 12
A B 2 Gee;Whizz;Hi 56 32
E   4 Btm;Lol 16 2
T   3 Whizz 13 3
```

List.txt

```
Gee
Whiz
Lol
```

Ideally output.txt looks like

```
some_data more_data other_data here yet_more_data etc
A B 2 Gee;Whiz;Hello 13 12
A B 2 Gee;Whizz;Hi 56 32
E   4 Btm;Lol 16 2
```

So I tried a shell script

```
for ids in List.txt 
do
grep $ids Data.txt >> output.txt
done
```

except I typed out everything (cut and paste actually) in `List.txt` in said script.

Unfortunately it gave me an `output.txt` including the last line, I assume as 'Whizz' contains 'Whiz'.

I also tried `cat Data.txt | egrep -F "List.txt"` and that resulted in `grep: conflicting matchers specified` -- I suppose that was too naive of me. The actual files: List.txt contains a sorted list of 985 words, Data.txt has 115576 rows with 17 columns.

Some help/guidance would be much appreciated thanks.

Comment: look for tutorials on the linux/unix `join` utility. Worst case, `man join` or `info join`. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
for ids in List.txt 
do
  grep "[TAB;]$ids[TAB;]" Data.txt >> output.txt
done
```

But it has two drawbacks:

1. "Data.txt" is scanned multiple times
2. You can get one line multiple times.

If it is problem try two step version:

```
cat List.txt | sed -e "s/.*/[TAB;]\0[TAB;]/g" > List_mod.txt
grep -f List_mod.txt Data.txt > output.txt
```

**Note:**
TAB character can be inserted by combination Ctrl-V following by Tab key in command line, and Tab character in editor. You have to check if your edit does not change tab to series of spaces.

Answer (score 0):

The UNIX tool for general text processing is "awk":

```
awk '
NR==FNR { list[$0]; next }
{
    for (word in list) {
        if ($0 ~ "[\t;]" word "[\t;]") {
            print
            next
        }
    }
}
' List.txt Data.txt > output.txt
```